# Making a query that only shows unique records

Tags: database, ms-access, unique

I have a table where duplicate entries in one of the columns is possible (emailAddress - some couples share them) and I would like to send email newsletters to them. Is there a way to make a select query where it only shows one copy of the email address if there are multiple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only emailAddress it is quite simple:

```
select distinct emailAddress from <YourTableNameHere>
```

*Edited according to request in comments.*

If you want to choose both distinct emailAddress and ANY customerName related to it then you must somehow tell SQL how to choose the customerName. The easiest way is to select i.e. MIN(customerName), then all other (usually those that are later in alphabet but it actually depends on collation) are discarded. Query would be:

```
select emailAddress, min(customerName) as pickedCustomerName
from <YourTableNameHere>
group by emailAddress
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I would like to select the customerName field also. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: OK, but as I understand, when emailAddress is the same, the customerName can still differ right? Wich of the related customerName(s) do you want to choose then?

Comment: Would it be possible to select the first one, and ignore the second?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DISTINCT keywprd, or you can GROUP BY.

```
SELECT DISTINCT email 
FROM table
```

Or

```
SELECT email, Count(ID)
FROM table
GROUP By email
```